# Node Js a simple server with query url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been looking at examples and I just cannot get how it
works.

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple I would presume and hoping if
someone could give me a hand?

I'm trying to have a server running that clients could connect to.
Lets say 127.0.0.1:8126
And if someone connects using a query string e.g. 127.0.0.1:8126/?
color=red
then every client that is currently on the server would have the
background of the page turn to red.

Could someone help me out with this?

Thanks so much!
Tyler

Comment: for real time page updates you should look into socket.io

Comment: There are no pages. There is no background. The server is a server, software running on some computer listening for connections. If you want to change the color of a webpage, you need to write client side code. That client side code can talk to a web server and act in response, but the changing of some browser's colors isn't something node.js does.

Comment: You should also use expressjs.com as your web framework if you asks me. It is really awesome....

Answer (score 1):

for realtime updates you should use socket.io or the like.

client.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type=text>
  <button>send css</button>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var socket = new io.Socket();
      socket.connect();
      socket.on('message',function(msg){
        $('body').css(msg);
      });
      $('button').click(function(){
         socket.send(JSON.parse($('input').val()));
      });
    });
   </script>
```

server.js

```
var fs=require("fs");
var clientpage = fs.readFileSync("client.html");
var http = require('http'),  
    io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.end(clientpage);
});
server.listen(8126);

var socket = io.listen(server); 
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
  client.on('message', function(data){ 
    socket.broadcast(data);
  });
});
```

It's a crude example since you need to type in the proper json for jquery.css() (eg {"background-color":"red"}) but it runs

[link](http://74.207.253.119:8126/)